# How to display data from a DB when Rows and Columns are inverted

Tags: php, mysql, sql, geolocation, google-maps-api-3

I have to deal with a table like this one with approximately a couple of hundreds of #id (and counting).

```
id     field_name     field_value  
1      name           pasta  
1      lat            41.27651  
1      long           11.45234  
2      name           pizza  
2      lat            43.53455 
2      long           12.62346
..     ....           ........
..     ....           ........
..     ....           ........
```

I need to build an XML file that allows me to add markers on Google Map with a structure like this:

```
<makers>
    <marker name="$name" lat="$lat" long="$long" />
    <marker name="$name" lat="$lat" long="$long" />
    (...)
</markers>
```

I am trying to do a query like this and then put all the info in arrays and play with some *foreach* but I am failing so hard that I can't go on.

```
$query = "  SELECT field_val
        FROM table
        WHERE field_name='Name'";
```

The main problem is that i am not able to work with a structure like this, given the fact that a probably better structure would have been like this

```
id    name    lat       long
1     pasta   41.27651  11.45234
2     pizza   43.53455  12.62346
..    ...     ...       ...
```

Please note that i can't change the way the entries go in the DB and that the structure of the table is more complicated than the one showed here (with approx. 15 field_name per id, not all of them necessary).

Sorry for the poor english and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(fieldname='name', field_value, NULL)) AS 'name', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(fieldname='lat', field_value, NULL)) AS 'lat', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(fieldname='long', field_value, NULL)) AS 'long' 
FROM table 
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: Stevie, thanks for your answer. Whit this code (with GROUP BY id) I can successfully put lat & long inside an array but i don't know how to retrieve the correct name.  Any suggestion?

Comment: This is perfect, i have now the right array! ES: Array
( [sub_id] => 11 [name] => Roberto [lat] => 41.892733292110904 [long] => 12.472159593115293). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks good. Now assuming that you always will need 3 lines to have full data, try the following untested code

```
$myXmlData = '<makers>'; // create first line of your xml

$myCoutner = 0;
$query = "  SELECT field_value FROM table ORDER BY id ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $myCoutner++;
    if ($myCoutner<=3)  // for the 3 first lines
    {
        $myMarker_data .= ' name = "'.stripslashes($row['field_value']).'" ';
        $myMarker_data .= ' lat = "'.stripslashes($row['field_value']).'" ';
        $myMarker_data .= ' long = "'.stripslashes($row['field_value']).'" ';
    }

    // if we have data
    if ($myCoutner==3)
    {
        if ($myMarker_data!='')
        {
            // add data to main xml
            $myXmlData .= '<marker '.$myMarker_data.' />';
        }

        $myCoutner = 0;  // reset coutner to start clunting 3 new lines
        $myMarker_data = ''; // reset var to hold temp data
    }
}
$myXmlData .= '</markers>';  // create last line of your xml
```

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the exhaustive answer but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: ok whats the error? i don't have something like your example in my localahost to work with, so i type untested code. I hope the comments can guide you to the logic of the script

Answer (score 0):

What you're having there is EAV model (Entity-Attribute-Value) and if you want to "invert" (proper term is pivot), then you either use PHP for that or you self-join the table so many times as you have "columns". In order to produce a result from MySQL that would give you column based layout that represents `name`, `lat`, `long` - you'd self-join the table on `id` column 3 times.

Comment: Michael, thanks for you answer. I already knew about Pivot but I am not able to do it properly, so i was looking for something else (like a PHP way).